# How can I view work items of others in Team Foundation Service?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using the new [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com) with Visual Studio 2010.

Currently I just have two users setup as the default project team. I am the first user.

I am able to assign work items to the other user. But I am not able to view his work items, or even if I can, I am unable to figure out where I can view all the work items.

[image: screenshot showing work items tab in team foundation service.]

In the screenshot above, in the work items tab, I only see the my work items. I can't see all work items.

As for the permissions, I am in the following groups:

`Project Collection Administrators`
`Project Administrators`
`Team Foundation Administrators`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on `New` then `Query`.
Then select `Assigned To` from `Field` option and in `Value` field select your desired user.

Comment: I just created a new query called ALL_TASKS (TeamProject=@Project AND Work Item Type=Task AND State=Any). In this way, I am able to view all tasks. I feel this query should be a default query in My Queries or General Queries.

Comment: You can save this query by clicking `Save` button. You can also add another condition to the query by clicking in `Click to add a new clause`.

Comment: Yup! I did that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look at the iteration planning tools as well; they allow you to roll up tasks by user or their associated User Story.